"a little better" VS "little better"
the textbook "The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 549:
(1) They spent a lot of money, but it’s little better than it was before.
my variant:
(2) They spent a lot of money, but it’s a little better than it was before.
The internet says "little" has a negative connotation and "a little" has a positive one. But in this example I can't see them. To me, (1) and (2) are the same.
So could you tell me please what's the difference between (1) and (2)?

The internet is right. The first can be understood as "not much, if any" and the second as "a small improvement".

Your variant makes no sense, as is.  You need "only a little better" to justify but. The word  only spins it negative.

How are you feeling now that you've had some sleep?  --Little better  (still feeling not good).   A littlee better ( somewhat better).   I've had a lot of sleep but I'm feeling only a little better.  I've had a lot of sleep and I'm feeling a little better.
